# How can I dequeue multiple queues simultaneously without waiting on each other in a hosted service?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Hey guys I could use some collaborative brain power here. I have a hosted service
that I'm creating that will take care of long-running processes.

We have many SQL Tables that will have jobs run against them in respective queues. These table job queues need to run parallel to each other for each respective table and every table job queue should run its own jobs sequentially. Splitting each table in their own queue is to help alleviate timing issues as some tables are huge and will take an hour per job while smaller tables will take minutes.

I'm at a mental block at the moment on how to dequeue all the queues properly in parallel in a hosted service. Table 1 can finish 10 jobs in the amount of time it takes Table 2 to finish 1 job. This is the desired outcome if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
public class Program

{

    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        var tableQueue = new Dictionary<string, Queue>();

        var tableNames = new List<string>() { "Table1", "Table2", "Table100" };

        foreach (var name in tableNames)

        {

            if (!tableQueue.ContainsKey(name))

                tableQueue.Add(name, new Queue());

        }



        // Another Hosted Service Will Periodically Load

        // the Table Queues with Job Numbers from a job table

        // that need to be processed

        tableQueue["name"].Enqueue("id of job to pickup from job table");

    }

}
```

Comment: just simply run one long-running Task per Table queue. In `Task.Factory.StartNew` Method you can passe `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. also use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` if there is another thread which is `Enqueueing` because `Queue` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @AliZeinali I hate to be a bother but do you mind giving me a rough example? I'm having a hard time following

Comment: of course, just to be sure should these jobs be in SQL, because if you are just looking for queueing job between multiple process there is better tools for this job, like RabbitMq

Comment: And where do you wanna run these jobs? In asp.net core or console app?

Comment: @AliZeinali yeah it's basically a simple table in SQL called Jobs that will drive various data scrub, load, and check operations. The jobs will have an Id, Table Name, Status, Action and NextScheduledTime. Every table will have jobs queued up and need to be executed at the time provided (a scheduler).  These jobs are all C# functions that we run manually today.  Do you still think RabbitMQ is a good candidate for this? I've used it lightly in the past but for stuff that needed to be immediately executed

Comment: asp.net core is where the jobs are now. I was planning to leverage background services (hosting service) to do all this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your situation is just creating a job scheduler there is already a good one: [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

But if you wanna run multiple queue in parallel you can use this class:

```
    public class JobRunner
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, Channel<string>> _channels = new Dictionary<string, Channel<string>>();

        private static List<string> tableNames = new List<string>() { "table1", "table2" };

        public JobRunner()
        {
            foreach(var table in tableNames)
            {
                var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<string>(1000);
                _channels.Add(table, channel);
            }
        }


        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var taskList = new List<Task>();
            foreach(var item in _channels)
            {
                var table = item.Key;
                var channel = item.Value;
                Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        string jobId = await channel.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
                        await RunJobAsync(jobId);
                    }
                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                taskList.Add(task);
            }

            return Task.WhenAll(taskList);
        }

        public static async Task EnqueueJobAsync(string tableName, string jobId)
        {
            if(_channels.TryGetValue(tableName, out var channel))
            {
                await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(jobId);
            }
        }

        private Task RunJobAsync(string jobid)
        {
            //load and run your job
            
        }
    }
```

```
    public class JobLoader
    {
        private static List<string> tableName = new List<string>() { "table1", "table2" };
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
            foreach(var table in tableName)
            {
                var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        //query to database and load some jobid
                        IEnumerable<string> ids = await LoadSomeIds(table);

                        if (ids.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (var id in ids)
                            {
                                await JobRunner.EnqueueJobAsync(table, id);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(1000);
                        }


                    }
                }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                taskList.Add(task);
            }

            return Task.WhenAll(taskList);
        }
    }
```

It will create one channel and one long-running task per table so each table will has it's own task which try to read jobids and run them.

And you should call EnqueueJobAsync("tablename", "jobid") to enqueue jobids

The ThreadPool will handle other part like creating thread if it needed or kill a thread if no more needed.

I also create Channel bounded to 1000 item you are free to change it to any number base on your business. also you can create unbounded channel but that's not recommended. because if your table be to large and your producer(enqueuer) be very faster than your consumer(dequeuer) it could cause a huge amount of ids be loaded and cause memory problem.

You can find more about `Channel<T>` type [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).

Comment: wow this is great, trying it out now man. I noticed HangFire in my searches and it looks promising but the real need to run multiple queues in parallel as you pointed out